# EXCEL: automatically apply the same formula to a range of cells

Tags: excel-formula

I believe there is some kind of automatic way to apply the same formula to a range of cells. A column is fine, but a more complex range would be much appreciated.

For example, say we have

```
    A       B     C           D       E        F          G
1  alice   bob    A+B               elias   Franckie    A+..+F
2  10       33    (formula)         15       22        (copy)
3  20       33    (copy)            15       15        (copy)      
4  15       33    (copy)            15       15        (copy)
```

I would like to edit the formula in `C2` : `SUM($A2:B2)` (note the mix of relative and absolute), and when I hit enter, have it expand to the whole `C` column (and ideally also the `G` column)

**Context**: My goal is to write a complex formula with lookups (using both relative and absolute references), and rely on consistency checks for debugging; without the hassle (and errors) of copy-pasting to several places manually

**Note 1** : Google search keeps giving answers like "use copy-paste" or "drag the small handle in the corner of the cell". That is not enough: I'm looking for a way to have the whole range auto-update when I hit enter

**Note 2** : The absolute ideal would be `USE_A_COPY_OF_FORMULA_WRITTEN_IN($C$2)` but I doubt it exists

**Note 3** : On last resource I would write a copy-paste macro, but I'd really like to keep my sheet macro-free

Comment: use a table (Insert > table) then the whole column gets updated automatically

Comment: @Ike: Seems to work great for a single range (`C2:C5`)  but not for a complex one (`C2:C5,H2:H5`). But that's till a huge step forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
=LET(range,DROP(HSTACK(A:A,B:B,D:D,E:E),1),
     TAKE(
          SCAN(0,
               FILTER(range,
                      TAKE(range,,-1)<>""),
               LAMBDA(a,b,
                      a+b))
          ,,-1))
```

Where HSTACK is used to stack whatever column you want to sum cumulatively.

*I referenced whole rows, and used DROP to not include the header, but it's better to narrow the range(s) down to for instance `A2:A5,B2:B5, ..`*

SCAN takes care of the cumulative sum cell by cell, row by row. It produces an array the height and width of the range used to sum.
(2nd) TAKE makes sure only the last column of the cumulative array will be spilled.

1st TAKE makes sure that a row's cumulative sum is added only if the last column's value is not empty.
Note that if any cell in the last column is not submitted the total row would be omitted the way it's written now.

Comment: A whole lot of functions I never heard about. Gotta dive into the doc !! :)